# How to declare vcard document type in xcode plist file

Tags: ios, vcf-vcard, info-plist

I would like my App to open for VCards (.vcf format). I know that the type is known as `public.vcard` and has mime-type `text/vcard`.
How is this type registered in the info.plist?

I have declared many custom types (UTI) and that works for me, but the VCard is a known format and so far I did not manage to set it up. When I for example airdrop a vcf file, then iOS Contacts shows up, but not the "open with" dialog.

There is a similar question already, but the proposed solution does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16506340/4180386

Comment: The link you added works actually. I can see my app when I click the more button.

Comment: Scenario: I share a VCard (vcf file) from my Mac and Airdrop it to my iPhone. I expect my App to be among the Apps to be selected for that type of file. With the solution in the link above it does not work for me. iPhone Contacts open with the contact. No selection view appears.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the types handled by system apps that provide API access to the data (photos, contacts, calendars, etc) seem to only offer the system app as an airdrop destination. Other types work fine and result in the “open with” alert as you pointed out.

Comment: During the period of time discussed, I tested an app that was supposed to do this, and we found that the system just didn't see the extra handler-apps reliably. Sometimes it did, sometimes it didn't. We could never figure out why, it happened across several handsets, several versions of iOS, even on the same build... Don't know if its better in today's (iOS 14) period.